# What are the differences between an EASA part-66 license and FAA A&P Aircraft Mechanic License?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, faa, easa, pilot-certification, engineer

what is the difference between EASA part-66 license and FAA A&P Aircraft Mechanic License? Are there any reasons for a company or individual to opt for the one or the other or both?

Comment: In the US (FAA) the aviation acronym AME stands for [Aviation Medical Examiner](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/). Instead, I think you must mean Aircraft Mechanic, A&P Mechanic, Aviation Maintenance Technician, or some equivalent.

Comment: Generally if you are regulated by EASA (Europe) you require part 66 engineers, if you are regulated by the FAA (USA) you require approved A&Ps. It's not really a case of a company having a choice. The individual would choose the path that is relevant to where they want to work.